# How to combine two functions?

Tags: powershell

There two functions:

- check if PC is waiting for reboot
- check if wuauserv is running - if it's stopped empty `$env:SystemRoot\SoftwareDistribution\Download` folder.

How do I combine these two in a single function to perform both, where if each check is true, then empty `$env:SystemRoot\SoftwareDistribution\Download`?

```
#function 1
If (Get-ChildItem "HKLM:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Component Based Servicing\RebootPending" -ErrorAction Ignore)
{
    return $true
}
If (Get-Item "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\WindowsUpdate\Auto Update\RebootRequired" -ErrorAction Ignore)
{
    return $true
}
If (Get-ItemProperty "HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager" -Name PendingFileRenameOperations -ErrorAction Ignore)
{
    return $true
}
try
{ 
    $util = [wmiclass]"\\.\root\ccm\clientsdk:CCM_ClientUtilities"
    $status = $util.DetermineIfRebootPending()
    If (($status -ne $null) -and $status.RebootPending)
    {
        return $true
    }
} catch{}
return $false

#function 2
$getservice = Get-Service -Name wuauserv
while($getservice.Status -eq 'Running')
{
    Start-Sleep -s 1800
    $getservice = Get-Service -Name wuauserv
}

Get-ChildItem -Path $env:SystemRoot\SoftwareDistribution\Download -Force -Recurse | Remove-Item -Force -Recurse -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've used the `WaitForStatus` method instead of a while loop, details here: http://www.powershellmagazine.com/2013/04/10/pstip-wait-for-a-service-to-reach-a-specified-status/

```
function Get-RebootPendingStatus {
    try
    {
        $util = [wmiclass]"\\.\root\ccm\clientsdk:CCM_ClientUtilities"
        $status = $util.DetermineIfRebootPending()
    } catch{}

    If (Get-ChildItem "HKLM:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Component Based Servicing\RebootPending" -ErrorAction Ignore)
    {
        return $true
    }
    ElseIf (Get-Item "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\WindowsUpdate\Auto Update\RebootRequired" -ErrorAction Ignore)
    {
        return $true
    }
    ElseIf (Get-ItemProperty "HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager" -Name PendingFileRenameOperations -ErrorAction Ignore)
    {
        return $true
    }
    ElseIf (($status -ne $null) -and $status.RebootPending)
    {
        return $true
    }
    Else {
        return $false
    }
}

function Watch-ForServiceStatus ($ServiceName,$ServiceStatus) {
    $service = Get-Service -Name $ServiceName
    $service.WaitForStatus($ServiceStatus)
    return $true
}

$RebootStatus = Get-RebootPendingStatus
$ServiceStatus = Watch-ForServiceStatus -ServiceName wuauserv -ServiceStatus Stopped

If (($RebootStatus -eq $true) -and ($ServiceStatus-eq $true)) {
    Get-ChildItem -Path "$env:SystemRoot\SoftwareDistribution\Download" -Force -Recurse | Remove-Item -Force -Recurse -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
}
```

Comment: I read, that he WaitForStatus method waits approximately 250 milliseconds between each status check. that's too heavy.

Comment: If (($ServiceStatus -eq $true) -and ($ServiceStatus-eq $true))? may be $RebootStatus.

Comment: 250ms is a quarter of a second. Why do you feel that is heavy? Yeah, the other one is $RebootStatus.

You should also know that Get-RebootPendingStatus could return multiple $true or $false values. That's just how Powershell Rolls. it returns everything. So you might want to optimize that function. For now, it will return $false for sure along with any other $true values.

Comment: Yes the missing $RebootStatus was a typo. 250ms isn't heavy when the check isn't resource intensive. If it was a file operation it would be longer but a quick check on a service status is nothing. 30mins however is a truly massive delay! If the service stopped 1 second after your check you'd be waiting a further 29 minutes 59 seconds, which is a massive waste of time. I've also refined the Reboot check so it only returns a single value.

Answer (score 0):

Well, for Starters, you gotta define the functions. Putting a comment as function 1 and function 2 is not enough. Put those things inside real functions and enclose it in a single larger function that dos what you want. I am not going to write your code for you but I will give you the logic.

```
#Define single function (Dont mind the weird names)
Function EmptySoftFolder-IfconditionsAreTrue
{
    Function Check-RebootPendingStatus
    {
       #Function1 code goes here.
    }

    Function Get-WUAServiceStatus
    {
       #Function2 code goes here
    }

    $Fn1 = Check-RebootPendingStatus
    $Fn2 = Get-WUAServiceStatus

    if ($Fn1 -and $Fn2)
    {
        #Empty the software distribution folder code goes here
    }
}
#Call the single function like this
EmptySoftFolder-IfconditionsAreTrue
```